# sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix - TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I seem to be getting an error when calling `confusion_matrix`, please see below. How can I get this to work?

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(normalisedArr_y5,predicted5)
```

Comment: The DataTypes are as follows predicted5           Int64 (244,) array([1,1,1,...,2,2,2]) normalisedArr_y5     Int64 (244,) array([1,1,1,...,5,5,5])

Comment: You should post the full stack trace

Comment: You are redefining `confusion_matrix` - use a different variable name.

Answer (score 2):

1 Be sure that both values are np arrays or lists as specified by @Roelant
2 do not assign to your variable's name the same name as the function name

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cfm = confusion_matrix(normalisedArr_y5,predicted5)
print(cfm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `normalisedArr_y5` and `predicted5` should be np.arrays or lists. Apparently one or both are not. You could try:

```
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(normalisedArr_y5.tolist(),predicted5.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was defining

```
normalisedArr_x5 = df.iloc[:,:-1]
```

and

```
normalisedArr_y5 = data.iloc[:,-1:]
```

and this **Error** was coming.

So just check if both the dataframe variables are the same (here `df`) and perform the steps again @Garch2017